# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code and below line has problem.

```
if ((hr==20)) document.write("Good Night"); document.getElementById('Night).style.display=''
```

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at Column 69
```

My div tag details are:

```
    <div id="Night" style="display: none;">
    <img src="Img/night.png" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 5%; height: auto; width: 100%; z-index: -2147483640;">
    <img src="Img/moon.gif" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 5%; height: 100%; width: auto; z-index: -2147483639;"></div>
```

Complete JavaScript:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    document.write("<dl><dd>")
    day = new Date()
    hr = day.getHours()
    if ((hr==1)||(hr==2)||(hr==3)||(hr==4) || (hr==5)) document.write("Should not you be sleeping?")
    if ((hr==6) || (hr==7) || (hr==8) || (hr==9) || (hr==10) || (hr==11)) document.write("Good Morning!")
    if ((hr==12)) document.write("Let's have lunch?")
    if ((hr==13) || (hr==14) || (hr==15) || (hr==16) || (hr==17)) document.write("Good afternoon!")
    if ((hr==18) || (hr==19)) document.write("Good late afternoon!")
    if ((hr==20)) document.write("Good Night"); document.getElementById('Night').style.display=''
    if ((hr==21)) document.write("Good Night"); document.getElementById('Night').style.display='none'
    if ((hr==22)) document.write("Good Night")
    if (hr==23) document.write("Oh My! It's almost midnight!")
    if (hr==0) document.write("Midnight!<br>It is already tomorrow!") document.write("</dl>")
    //--->
    </script>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Make sure your script is in a document ready handler - if you're trying to do things with the DOM before it's fully loaded, the DOM elements might not be available when you try to select them.

Comment: It sounds like the `<div>` Noite does not exist when you're calling this script. Try moving the javascript to the body of your `<body>` tag.

Comment: You need to provide a better picture of what you're doing. If you're trying to select an element, and there's no match, then how can anyone know what's wrong if we can't see your page?

Comment: You tagged this question as `jquery` but you don't seem to use it. Actually using jQuery would make it much easier.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In your script, this part:

```
document.getElementById('Noite')
```

must be returning `null` and you are also attempting to set the `display` property to an invalid value.  There are a couple of possible reasons for this first part to be `null`.

1. You are running the script too early before the document has been loaded and thus the `Noite` item can't be found.
2. There is no `Noite` item in your HTML.

I should point out that your use of `document.write()` in this case code probably signifies a problem.  If the document has already loaded, then a new `document.write()` will clear the old content and start a new fresh document so no `Noite` item would be found.

If your document has not yet been loaded and thus you're doing `document.write()` inline to add HTML inline to the current document, then your document has not yet been fully loaded so that's probably why it can't find the `Noite` item.

The solution is probably to put this part of your script at the very end of your document so everything before it has already been loaded.  So move this to the end of your body:

```
document.getElementById('Noite').style.display='block';
```

And, make sure that there are no `document.write()` statements in javascript after the document has been loaded (because they will clear the previous document and start a new one).

---

In addition, setting the `display` property to `"display"` doesn't make sense to me.  The valid options for that are `"block"`, `"inline"`, `"none"`, `"table"`, etc...  I'm not aware of any option named `"display"` for that style property.   See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for valid options for teh `display` property.

You can see the fixed code work here in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yVJY4/.  That jsFiddle is configured to have the javascript placed at the end of the document body so it runs after the document has been loaded.

---

P.S.  I should point out that your lack of braces for your `if` statements and your inclusion of multiple statements on the same line makes your code very misleading and unclear.

---

I'm having a really hard time figuring out what you're asking, but here's a cleaned up version of your code that works which you can also see working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QCxwr/.  Here's a list of the changes I made:

1. The script is located in the body, but after the content that it is referencing.
2. I've added `var` declarations to your variables (a good habit to always use).
3. The `if` statement was changed into an if/else which is a lot more efficient and more self-documenting as to what you're doing.
4. I've added braces for every `if` statement so it absolutely clear which statements are part of the `if/else` and which are not.
5. I've properly closed the `</dd>` tag you were inserting.
6. I've changed `style.display = '';` to `style.display = 'block';`.
7. I've added semicolons at the end of every statement (another good habit to follow).

The code:

```html
<div id="Night" style="display: none;">
    <img src="Img/night.png" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 5%; height: auto; width: 100%; z-index: -2147483640;">
    <img src="Img/moon.gif" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 5%; height: 100%; width: auto; z-index: -2147483639;">
</div>    
<script>
document.write("<dl><dd>");
var day = new Date();
var hr = day.getHours();
if (hr == 0) {
    document.write("Meia-noite!<br>Já é amanhã!");
} else if (hr <=5 ) {
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;Você não<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;devia<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;estar<br>dormindo?");
} else if (hr <= 11) {         
    document.write("Bom dia!");
} else if (hr == 12) {
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vamos<br>&nbsp;almoçar?");
} else if (hr <= 17) {
    document.write("Boa Tarde");
} else if (hr <= 19) {
    document.write("&nbsp;Bom final<br>&nbsp;de tarde!");
} else if (hr == 20) {
    document.write("&nbsp;Boa Noite"); 
    document.getElementById('Noite').style.display='block';
} else if (hr == 21) {
    document.write("&nbsp;Boa Noite"); 
    document.getElementById('Noite').style.display='none';
} else if (hr == 22) {
    document.write("&nbsp;Boa Noite");
} else if (hr == 23) {
    document.write("Ó Meu! Já é quase meia-noite!");
}
document.write("</dl></dd>");
</script>
```

Comment: This script displays a sentence these times was to display a gif moon so dark, the more it shows that did not work ... :/

Comment: @JK-ASP - I have no idea what your comment means.  If you want me to show you how it works with your HTML, you have to disclose your HTML which you have not done.  The point of the script is to make a div visible and the code I've suggested does that.  The div can contain an image or text or other divs or anything you want.  Please note my recent edit where you also have to set the `display` value to a valid argument.  You were setting it to `"display"` which is not a valid CSS option.

Comment: stretch document.getElementById ('Night'). style.display ='' serves to show the div, this div is just a gif of a moon, 8pm that should be displayed in the background.

Comment: @JK-ASP - so what is your question beyond what I've already answered?  My suggest code works just fine when the div contains an image too: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bSnnG/

Comment: this script is not displaying the div, that's the problem, I put as display='block' in the same way did not work.

Comment: @JK-ASP - then there is something else wrong with your page/scripts.  Clearly from my two demos the concept works if implemented properly.  Without seeing a link to your actual page or a demonstration of the problem put into a jsFiddle, we can't help any further.  The concept has been explained to you.  If you do not implement the concept correctly in a page that we cannot see, then we cannot help any further.

Comment: to explain, in the line "if ((hr == 20)) document.write (" Good Night "); document.getElementById ('Night'). style.display = 'block';" I can only run the part "if ((hr == 20)) document.write (" Good Night ")" and the other part not the result of some. I want to fix it.

Comment: @JK-ASP - your jsFiddle fails because you are using `document.write()` on a document that is already loaded.  As my answer explains, this clears the document and started a brand new document.  Thus, there is no div with the `id="Noite"`.  I'd suggest you stop using `document.write()`.  You can add content to your existing document dynamically with `document.createElement()` and `node.appendChild()`.

Comment: @JK-ASP - I've added a fixed copy of your code to my answer with a jsFiddle demo of that code.  Please study the changes and learn from them.

Comment: @JK-ASP - FYI, do you understand that when someone helps you solve your problem, you should click the green checkmark next to their answer?  This both gives them credit for providing the solution and earns you some reputation points for following the proper procedure on StackOverflow and indicates to the community which answer best served you.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `document.write` would overwrite your existing code therefore place your `div` before your javascript code. e.g.:

CSS:

```
#mydiv { 
  visibility:hidden;
 }
```

Inside your html file

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('mydiv').style.visibility='visible';
</script>
```

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a ' (single quote) after night.
right here **getElementById('Night**

Answer (score 2):

simply I think you are missing a single quote in your code

```
if ((hr==20)) document.write("Good Night"); document.getElementById('Night"here").style.display=''
```

it should be like this

```
if ((hr==20)) document.write("Good Night"); document.getElementById('Night').style.display=''
```

Answer (score 1):

For me my Script tag   was outside the body element. Copied it just before closing the body tag. This worked

```
enter code here
```

```
<h1 id = 'title'>Black Jack</h1>
<h4> by Meg</h4>

<p id="text-area">Welcome to blackJack!</p>
<button id="new-button">New Game</button>
<button id="hitbtn">Hit!</button>
<button id="staybtn">Stay</button>

 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible reason behind the error is that the JavaScript runs much earlier than the objects it requires from the webpage are loaded. The below codes will certainly solve the issues.

```
if ( document.getElementById('Night) )
    document.getElementById('Night).style.display=''";
```

It is always a good practice to check for the existence of a DOM object before calling an action on the Object.

Comment: Although it would get rid of the error it won't set the display style as 'none' as the OP wanted and would just skip this statement, leading to an unexpected result.

Comment: Hi Surana, I appreciate your opinion. Actually, such errors frequently occur when the JavaScript event listener is called before the target DOM object is loaded. However, if you check for the existence of the Object and the change in the DOM object didn't take place, certainly, there is an error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

this can also happen where you write an html tag after loading js script file

```
 <div id="MyBox" class="box"></div>
<script src="Script.js"></script>
```

now if i try to get `MyBox` and log it in console i

```
const box = document.getElementById("MyBox");
```

will get this kind of error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at Script.js:519:5
```

so try moving your external js tags

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late and answers are answered but for me problem was that I was selecting html elements incorrectly
I used this

```
let variable = document.querySelector('something');
```

instead of this

```
let variable = document.querySelector('.something');
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, the situation is I need to download flash game by embed tag and H5 game by iframe, I need a loading box there, when the flash or H5 download done, let the loading box display none. well, the flash one work well but when things go to iframe, I cannot find the property 'style' of null , so I add a clock to it , and it works

```
let clock = setInterval(() => {
        clearInterval(clock)
        clock = null
        document.getElementById('loading-box').style.display = 'none'
    }, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your source to the script may be in the incorrect place. Put the link to your JS page UNDER the /body.

```
    </body>
    <script src="Index.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "defer" to your  line in HTML

```js
<script src="Index.js" defer ></script>
```

It'll load the JS AFTER the page has been loaded.