# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.VB.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

This errors occurs when I try to click on the the drop down button. I am using Response.Write to write the HTML. I have to use response.write because the buttons are generated inside a function() which exists under a  `<script runat="server">` tag and I cannot add Html directly.

```
If blnIsAssm = True Then
    Response.Write("<img onclick=""changeNavPic('toggle" & lngCurrentLineNum & "'); toggleDisplay('tblparts" & lngCurrentLineNum & " ');"" id=""toggle" & lngCurrentLineNum & """src=""/Img/common/icons/Plus.gif"" width=""13"" height=""13"" border=""0"">")
Else
    'print only blank gif
    Response.Write("<img src=""/img/inv/template1/spacer.gif"" width=""10"" height=""10"" align=""left"" vspace=""0"" hspace=""0"" border=""0"">")
End If



<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/JavaScript1.2">

        var getID= document.getElementById ? true : false;

        function OpenPopup(varPage, varHeight) {
            winstyle='height=' + varHeight + ',width=495,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=yes,resizable=yes';
            window.open(varPage,null,winstyle);
        }

        function AddLetter(varletter) {
            // add a letter to the part number text box at the top of the page
            if (document.topsearch.start.value.length >= 25) {
                alert('To Many Letters For Part Number');
            }
            else {
                document.topsearch.start.value = document.topsearch.start.value + varletter;
            }
        }

        function BackSpacePartNum() {
            //Makes the part number textbox lose one char in length


            if (document.topsearch.start.value.length >= 1) {
                var pnumStr = document.topsearch.start.value;
                document.topsearch.start.value = pnumStr.substr(0,document.topsearch.start.value.length - 1);
            }
        }

        function ClearPartNum() {
            //Clears the part number search text at the top of the page
            document.topsearch.start.value = '';
        }

        function ToggleMenu(objOn, objOff) {
            if(!getID) return;
            var objOn = getRef(objOn);
            var objOff = getRef(objOff);

            objOn.style.display = "block";
            objOff.style.display = "none";
        }

        function MakeLeftBarNeutral() {
            // return the left bar to everything DE-SELECTED
        var obj = getRef('tblleft_partsupplier');
            obj.style.display = "none";

        }

        function getRef(obj){
            return (typeof obj == "string") ? document.getElementById(obj) : obj;
        }
    var getID= document.getElementById ? true : false;

                    // This toggles the actual display of the object, will completely remove it 
                    // from the screen.

                    function toggleDisplay(obj){
                        if(!getID) return;
                        var obj = getRef(obj);

                        if(obj.style.display == "none"){
                            obj.style.display = "block";
                        }
                        else{
                            obj.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }


                    // This will toggle the navigation pictures (plus, minus) for the given obj ref
                    // Used For Multi-Level Tables Such as Required Parts, Full Assembly List
                    function changeNavPic(obj){
                        if(!getID) return;
                        var obj = getRef(obj);

                        if(obj.src == '/Img/common/icons/plus.gif'){
                            obj.src = '/Img/common/icons/minus.gif';
                        }
                        else{
                            obj.src = '/Img/common/icons/plus.gif';
                        }
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: That sounds like a javascript error.  Why don't you post the javascript?  The server-side VB is basically useless for troubleshooting this.

Comment: If you knew what line of code the error is happening on then you would know the problem.  Try debugging or using the developer tools of the browser.

Comment: The error occurs in the function toggleDisplay(obj), at 
  if(obj.style.display == "none"){
                            obj.style.display = "block";
I am not sure why the error happens, because the exact function is used on other pages as well and it works flawlessly. :( 
Thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: The answer here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235345/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null

Comment: Anyone with any other info? I still havent got this to work.