# Chage DOM property after form submission php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form submit in which if an error occurs then i want the border of the text element to be red.

```
if(isset($_POST["forgotsubmit"])){
if(!empty($_POST["forgotemail"])){      
    else{
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('forgotemaill').style.border= 'border: 2px solid red';</script>";
    }
}
}
```

Now after this in console shows

```
forgot-password:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at forgot-password:61
(anonymous) @ forgot-password:61
```

Comment: In your actual code did you really type an extra "l" on the end of "forgotemail"?

Comment: @Ashish Choudhary Just looking at your javascript syntax.
Try dropping "border: "

Comment: @Pointy Yes its is forgotemaill only

Comment: @Community I believe that this was marked Duplicate out of context.
The OP here is no doubt doing a server side check of a textbox, and from what I can glean, there is an existing label on the page hence the extra 'l' at the end. Meaning the answer in the duplicate (provided)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235345/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null] has nothing to do with solving this particular question, as the Element already exists on the page. There are different reasons you can receive this error. Please un-mark this as a duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The current error indicates that it cannot find an element. If you look closely you will notice there is a typo in the JS

document.getElementById('forgotemaill') <-- should this be forgotemail ?

Comment: <input type="text" name="forgotemail" id="forgotemaill" class="form-control" 
 placeholder="E-mail Address"/>

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your javascript syntax. Try dropping "border: "

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('forgotemaill').style.border= '2px solid red';</script>";
```

**You can try this instead**:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('forgotemaill').setAttribute('style', 'border: 2px solid red');</script>";
```

This should work, as it will force a style to exist on the object.

Your original is assuming that 'style' exists and you are able to change it's value.

Comment: still the same brother :(

Comment: @AshishChoudhary - I think this will help you along with the update to my answer [How to load and run javascript via Ajax/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js).