# Javascript querySelector not working even with my script at the end of the html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm learning javascript and used this youtube video as an example: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLc8NB2JyxE&
He does not include source code but I have made sure that my code is exactly how it is in the video. 
The tutorial walks through how to use html, css, and javascript to make a navbar that changes as you scroll down the screen. Any example of this error I could find had a solution of "put the script at the end of the html body" but mine is already there and I'm not sure why the script is not loading.

this is the error:

```
app.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at app.js:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at IntersectionObserver.navCheck (app.js:16)
(anonymous) @ app.js:28
navCheck @ app.js:16
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>PhotoGem | slogan here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h1>PhotoGem</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a data-page="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a data-page="project" href="#">Project</a></li>
          <li><a data-page="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section data-index="0" class="home">
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </section>
      <section data-index="1" class="project">
        <h2>Projects</h2>
      </section>
      <section data-index="2" class="contact">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: white;
}
nav {
  min-height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav h1,
nav ul {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section h2 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
}

.home {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #f46b45, #eea849);
}

.project {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #005c97, #363795);
}
.contact {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #e53935, #e35d5b);
}

.bubble {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top orange, yellow);
}
```

app.js

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const bubble = document.querySelector(".bubble");
const gradients = [
  "linear-gradients(to right top, #f46b45, #eea849)",
  "linear-gradients(to right top, #005c97, #363795)",
  "linear-gradients(to right top, #e53935, #e35d5b)"
];

const options = {
  threshold: 0.7
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(navCheck, options);

function navCheck(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const className = entry.target.className;
    const activeAnchor = document.querySelector(`[data-page=${className}]`);
    const gradientIndex = entry.target.getAttribute("data-index");
    const coords = activeAnchor.getBoundingClientRect();
    const directions = {
      height: coords.height,
      width: coords.width,
      top: coords.top,
      left: coords.left
    };
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      bubble.style.setProperty("left", `${directions.left}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty("top", `${directions.top}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty("width", `${directions.width}px`);
      bubble.style.setProperty("height", `${directions.height}px`);
    }
  });
}

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

Comment: Looks like the div "bubble" is missing in the html document. Have a look here, this seems like a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235379/4474165

Comment: Seems like your div bubble is missing from the `HTML`