# Changing div width with a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i am trying to learn JS, React and Node.js. Now i am trying to change the width of a div with a button but i'm getting always the same error, that it "Cannot read property 'style' of null

Here is my JS

```
var sideNav = document.getElementById("side-nav");
var linksSideNavTop = document.getElementById("links-side-nav-top");
var linksSideNavBottom = document.getElementById("links-side-nav-bottom");


function openMenuTablet() {
    if (sideNav.style.width === '70px') {
        sideNav.style.width = '300px';
        linksSideNavTop.style.display = "block";
        linksSideNavBottom.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        sideNav.style.width = '70px';
        linksSideNavTop.style.display = "none";
        linksSideNavBottom.style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

Here the CSS

```
#side-nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #454545;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure sideNav is not null by the time you call openMenuTablet(), checkout the React Component lifecycle to understand how and when things happen

Comment: A probable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235345/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null

Comment: Of the code you provide, I assume you are manipulating DOM manually with HTML and vanilla JS, not React. One of the `getElementId` call return `null`, which means the ids are incorrect or the DOM is not ready for you to traverse. Please place your script tag right before the end of the body tag.
This article could give you more insights: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-browser-rendering-works-behind-scenes/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this working example:

```js
function changeWidth() {
  document.getElementById('myContainer').style.width = '500px'
}
```

```css
#myContainer {
  width: 250px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="myContainer"></div>
<button onclick="changeWidth()">Change width</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answers Are correct, also I can show my example how to do that by `.classList.toggle()`

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.classList.toggle("toggle")
})
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s
}

.box.toggle{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button>Toggle Class List</button>
```

if your class list has `toggle` your div width increases and and in Javascript `.toggle` method removes and adds your passed classList which is `"toggle"` in our case

Answer (score 0):

The error "*Cannot read property 'style' of null*" means that the code to get the element (`document.getElementById()`) isn't retrieving (founding) an element with that particular ID.

I would suggest for you to double check that you don't have duplicated ID with the same exact name and also to move the `document.getElementById()` inside your function.

```
function openMenuTablet() {
    var sideNav = document.getElementById("side-nav");
    var linksSideNavTop = document.getElementById("links-side-nav-top");
    var linksSideNavBottom = document.getElementById("links-side-nav-bottom");

    if (sideNav.style.width === '70px') {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Also a good alternative to `document.getElementById()` would be `document.querySelector()`:

```
document.querySelector("h1");         // Search html tag "h1"
document.querySelector(".rect");      // Search class name "rect"
document.querySelector("#square");    // Searcd id name "square"
```

For last, to know if you are really founding and retrieving the intended element you can for example `console.log()` the var element:

```
var sideNav = document.getElementById("side-nav");
console.log(sideNav);

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have declared the items with the id´s of `links-side-nav-top`, `links-side-nav-bottom` and `side-nav`?

You can try to `console.log(linksSideNavTop);` to check existence of id.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.