# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript

I, trying to make a div clickable so it will be redirected to a different document or site but got that error.
However, it works with the old way of using the onclick as an attribute inside the element.

```
var examscol = document.getElementById("exam-col1");
function examCol() {
  return window.location.assign("https://www.w3schools.com")
}

examscol.addEventListener("click", examCol);
```

Any suggestions on why it isn't working with this way ?

Comment: You don't read `style` in your code here, so the error comes from a different place.

Comment: where do u think the error might come from? because I'm using bootstrap scss and css files .

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. Problem

The problem is that the id of the  element is not `exam-col1`. When I change the id of the  element to `exam-col` I get the following error <sup>[1]</sup>:

```
Error
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')",
}
```

###### 2. Hint

The frame cannot be displayed when the URL's `X-Frame-Options` field is set to `SAMEORIGIN`. The `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` <sup>[2]</sup>. That's why I changed the targeted URL.

```js
/* If there is no item with an id of "exam-col1" on the page, you will get a "null" error. */
var examscol = document.getElementById("exam-col1");

function examCol() {
 return window.location.assign("https://www.wikipedia.com")
}

examscol.addEventListener("click", examCol);
```

```css
.clickable {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note that the id of the item is "exam-col1". -->
<div id="exam-col1" class="clickable">Open</div>
```

---

<sup>1 - [JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235345/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null/19235379)</sup>
<sup>2 - [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)</sup>

Comment: I did this but after refreshing page, it keeps on displaying ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')```

Comment: i guess have to use the old way of using the method as an attribute in the element but it doesn't make me professional

Comment: @Icezua I updated the post.

Comment: ```<div class="row exam-row justify-content-sm-center">
        <div id="exam-col1" class="exam-col col-md-5 private input-group-text justify-content-sm-center clickable"> Private School</div>
        <div id="exam-col2" class="exam-col col-md-5 public input-group-text justify-content-sm-center"> Private School</div>
      </div>```  Thats the html code for the js file

Answer (score 1):

I thinks nothing wrong in this code it something else referring to some style error .you can check your html if its ok and also show you code to insure whats the problem. Its would be pleasure