# Error 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')' when attempting to display a Vue view

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a header with an `@click` in my body. When clicked, a Vue view should be displayed, but instead I get the error:

`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`

---

From [what I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235379/9686427) the error occurs because `document.getElementById("view")` returns `null`, which can happen for a couple of reasons:

1. The script is running before the document has been loaded and thus no `view` item can be found.
2. There is no `view` item.

Since there certainly *is* a `view` item, I'm guessing the first reason is causing the error, yet I do not understand why nor how it can be fixed.

---

The following is the code in my App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <h1 @click="showInfo()">Header</h1>
  <div class="view" style="display: none">
    <AnotherView />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.view {
}
</style>

<script>
import AnotherView from "./views/AnotherView.vue";

export default {
  components: { AnotherView },
  methods: {
    showInfo() {
      document.getElementById("view").style.display = "block";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using direct DOM access in the first place? The correct way to handle this sort of this appears to be covered in [step 4 of the Vue.js tutorial](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-4) (although [step 8](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-8) seems to be better for twiddling lists of classes which is the better way to apply CSS).

Comment: N.B. _getElementById_ takes element from id not from class, as @Quentin says this is not the correct way to get the element with Vue

Comment: @Quentin you are right, and thanks to your and Sfili_81's comments I solved the issue. Feel free to post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You are consulting a class in `getElementById()`, the correct thing is to get it by the ID as the user @Sfili_81 mentioned.

And you should also use `$ref` to do this treatment.

```
<template>
  <h1 @click="showInfo()">Header</h1>
  <div ref="view-ref" class="view" style="display: none">
    <AnotherView />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.view {
}
</style>

<script>
import AnotherView from "./views/AnotherView.vue";

export default {
  components: { AnotherView },
  methods: {
    showInfo() {
      this.$refs.style.display = "block";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional class like below source
use `isShowInfo` Boolean flag (if you want, toggle)
and Edit style source block class is on/off

```html
<template>
  <h1 @click="showInfo()">Header</h1>
  <div class="view" :class="{ 'block': isShowInfo }">
    <AnotherView />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.view {
  display: none;
  &.block {
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
import AnotherView from "./views/AnotherView.vue";

export default {
  components: { AnotherView },
  data () {
    isShowInfo: false,
  },
  methods: {
    showInfo() {
      this.isShowInfo = true
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).